# What is the difference between Control and ContentControl in Silverlight/WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, silverlight

Please explain the actual differences between **Control and ContentControl** because googling didn't yielded good results.

Actually, I'm facing one issue related to this:
I have a **Autocompletebox control** (*inheriting from **ContentControl***). For a new value entered by user, the corresponding Property's **Mode=TwoWay** is working fine and Property's value is getting updated in ViewModel and same repeats if the user enters another new value. But if a previously entered value is again entered by the user then the Property's value is not being updated.

So I guess that may be this **Autocompletebox control** should inherit from **Control class** rather than **ContentControl**.

Am I correct?, please add your inputs and feedbacks.

**EDIT - Adding pseudo code::**

**Control class:-**

```
public class MyAutoBox : ContentControl
{
    public int MyProp
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(MyPropProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyPropProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("MyProp", typeof(int), typeof(MyAutoBox), new PropertyMetadata(0));

}
```

**ViewModel:-**

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase, INavigationAware
{
    private int MyProp;

    public int MyProp
    {
        get { return MyProp; }
        set
        {
            if (MyProp != value)
            {
                MyProp = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => MyProp);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Xaml:**

```
<MyControls:MyAutoBox Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Margin="10,0"
                    CanTypeIn="True"
                    MyProp="{Binding MyProp,  Converter={StaticResource NullToNumericConverter},Mode=TwoWay}"
<MyControls/>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Its not the MS AutoCompleteBox. It is a custom control developed by us, which inherits from ContentControl.

Answer (score 1):

ContentControl is actually inherited from Control class. So the issue does not appear due to that. Property Changed mechanism will work, when a property value really changed. If the new value and old value are equal, there is no need to update the ViewModel.

Apart from that, Control class is the base class for most of the UI Elements in WPF. It holds the properties like Background, Foreground, Font, etc.

ContentControl is a class which represents an element, that can accept single item as child. For example, ListBoxItem, ComboBoxItem, etc are ContentControls.

Comment: I will give an example, lets say I have entered 100, then removed it; then entered 200, 300, so on....till this point it works fine for each of these values. But if I repeat any of the previously entered value again, say 200 then this time Property changed not happening; due to which my property value in viewmodel is not getting updated. Hope that explains.

Comment: @xpertprogrammer it would help a lot if you could reproduce the issue in some minimal example code.

Comment: @McGarnagle Though I cant provide you a working sample app (because it needs all supporting classes, DLLs, etc), I am providing the pseudo code for the class and xaml and updating my Question. Please have a look and suggest.

Comment: @McGarnagle Hi. Have you gone thru the code? Please give your valuable inputs.